# Ubuntu One webinterface to manage contacts

Tags: ubuntu-one, contacts

I have ubuntu one mobile package and I would like to change and store my contacts on the computer, because its easier than on the phone and backed up. I don't want to use google sync, as they have enough data.

The problem with the web interface is, that I can't add information to a contact. For example, I can change a number or an emailadress which already exists but I can't add a further email adress, the postal adress. Pusing the button "add phone number" leads into no happening.

I tried the newest opera, firefox and chromium.
How to add information to a contact? / why is the webinterface buggy?

I pay money.

Answer (score 3):

It's an intermittent problem we're chasing down, we hope to get it fixed soon. You should be able to reload the page, wait until everything has downloaded, and then add more information without problems.

If not, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to [bug #767782](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/767782) which should be deployed within a week or so.